# ExpressJS : Strange String Comparation

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm doing this:

```
res.jsonp({
     userId:  user._id,
     spotUserId:  spot.user._id, 
     condition:  (user._id === spot.user._id)
});
```

And the result is this:

```
{
    "userId": "551192836bff030fb657777c",
    "spotUserId": "551192836bff030fb657777c",
    "condition": false
}
```

I don't understand why the condition is false... Help me!

Comment: try `==` operator, it should work.

Comment: the same result with == operator ... The problem I think is because ObjectIds in Moongose are compared .id and not ._id :) I don't knew it before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I solved the problem.

In ExpressJS for compare Mongoose ObjectsID, is **.id** not **_id**.

Example:

```
res.jsonp({
    userId:  user._id,
    spotUserId:  spot.user._id, 
    condition:  (user.id === spot.user.id)
});
```

Result:

```
{
    "userId": "551192836bff030fb657777c",
    "spotUserId": "551192836bff030fb657777c",
    "condition": true
}
```